# csvjoin on multiple columns

Tags: python, bash, csv, join, inner-join

I have the following csv files that I would like to `Inner Join`

**CSV 1: Trip_Data.csv (250MB)**

```
head -2 rand_trip_data_1.csv 

medallion,hack_license,vendor_id,rate_code,store_and_fwd_flag,pickup_datetime,dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_time_in_secs,trip_distance,pickup_longitude,pickup_latitude,dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude
DFD2202EE08F7A8DC9A57B02ACB81FE2,51EE87E3205C985EF8431D850C786310,CMT,1,N,2013-01-07 23:54:15,2013-01-07 23:58:20,2,244,.70,-73.974602,40.759945,-73.984734,40.759388
```

**CSV 2: Trip_Fare (1.70GB)**

```
head -2 trip_fare_1.csv

medallion, hack_license, vendor_id, pickup_datetime, payment_type, fare_amount, surcharge, mta_tax, tip_amount, tolls_amount, total_amount
89D227B655E5C82AECF13C3F540D4CF4,BA96DE419E711691B9445D6A6307C170,CMT,2013-01-01 15:11:48,CSH,6.5,0,0.5,0,0,7
```

I want to merge the two CSV files on the following columns: `medallion`, `hack_license`, `pickup_datetime`.

I am using `csvjoin` but it only permits me to join on one column from each csv file. Is there a way, I can add more columns in the join condition.

Query to join on `medallion` only using `csvjoin`:

```
csvjoin -c medallion rand_trip_data_1.csv trip_fare_1.csv > trip_data_1.csv
```

Query in `bash` (but it is doesn't work)

```
join -t , -1 1,2,6 -2 1,2,4 rand_trip_data_1.csv trip_fare_1.csv > trip_data_1.csv
join: illegal field number -- 1,2,6
```

I am open to alternative bash/python suggestions as well. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to use [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to solve my problem.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("test_rand.csv")
fare = pd.read_csv("test_fare.csv")

merged = pd.merge(data, fare, how='left', on=['medallion', 'hack_license', 'pickup_datetime'])
merged.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)
```